# Android ListView ItemClick Event

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I've created standard Android `Dialog` that has a `ListView` inside of it.

I've also created Adapter for this `ListView` and I am passing it.

```
this.MyMultiSelectListView.Adapter = MyMultiSelectListAdapter;
```

And all that works fine. I can see the list and everything.

But there is a image on this layout and I want to change the image when that item is clicked.
So this is what I tried:

```
this.MyMultiSelectListView.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) => {
    var clickedItem = MyMultiSelectListAdapter.GetItem(e.Position);

    if(clickedItem.Selected == false) {
        clickedItem.Selected = true;
        MyMultiSelectListAdapter.imgView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.true_image);
    } else {
        clickedItem.Selected = false;
        MyMultiSelectListAdapter.imgView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.false_image);
    }
};
```

I also tried to reload it once the image was set but that didn't seem to do anything.

anything I am missing here?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

The image changing issue was solved by `SetBackgroundResource` to `SetImageDrawable` and adding @Mây Và Bão's answer at the end of the click event.

But it doesn't completely fix my issue.
It only changes image for the LAST ITEM in the list, no matter which item I click on.
How can I make sure it does it for that one specific item?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `MyMultiSelectListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` it will refresh the listview

Comment: That didn't do anything. the bool value of the clickedItem is changing so I know the condition is working. but the image doesn't update.

Comment: Actually your answer worked.  Instead of `SetBackgroundResource`, I have to use `SetImageDrawable`.  But now the problem is, it only changes the image for the last item on the list, no matter which item I click on.